# jQuery selector that excludes a subtree of the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a jQuery selector that will grab all elements of class **A** that are not descendants of class **B**?

Example:

```
<body>
   <div class=report-value id=overview></div>
   <div class=panels>
      <div class=report-value id=sales></div>
      <div class=report-value id=training></div>
      <div class=report-value id=hr></div>
   </div>
   <div class=report-value id=summary></div>
</body>
```

For the above example, the need is to select all `.report-value` elements that are not descendants of the `.panels` element.  The report values are computationally heavy and need to be calculated only when actually displayed.

Something like:

```
var elems = $('.report-value:excludeTree(.panels)');
```

which would return a jQuery object containing only `#overview` and `#summary`.

Performance is important for this web application.

Comment: Here's the final performance test: http://jsfiddle.net/AyJmL/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) filter out those elements

```
$('.report-value').not('.panels .report-value')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bTyRL/)

Comment: There's now a performance test, and your answer (**Solution #2**) is the fastest so far.  After a few days, I'll accept the fastest (and cleanest) answer.  JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AyJmL/

Comment: FYI - `$('.report-value:not(.panels .report-value)')` is also possible, but apparently is way slower (#4 in http://jsfiddle.net/AyJmL/4/).
Thought this might interest anyone trying to optimize the syntax here.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
var elems = $('.report-value').filter(function(){ 
                 return $(this).closest('.panels').length ==0; 
            });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/7Nrz3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var allpanels=$('body>.report-value');
```

Comment: This selector didn't seem work for me.  You can check if I implemented it correctly at: http://jsfiddle.net/AyJmL/ (see **Solution #3**)

Comment: sorry ! the class name is changed. check now

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body > .report-value')
```

or

```
$('.report-value').each(function(){
if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('.panels'))
{
//use query
}
});
```

Comment: These are now on the updated test page (**Solution #4** and **Solution #5**), but they both fail.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/AyJmL/3/

Comment: try this:

$('.report-value').each(function(){
if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('panels') && !$(this).parents().eq(1).hasClass('panels'))
{
console.log($(this));
}
});

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.report-value').each(function(){
if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('panels') && !$(this).parents().eq(1).hasClass('panels'))
{
console.log($(this));
}
});
```

It console only ur required divs